# Input and label on same line without form-horizontal and col-XX classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have label and input in one line. I know about `form-horizontal`, `form-inline`. But I have some `p` tags above my `label` and `input` and them all look good.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="pull-left">Name: <strong>John Smith</strong></p>
        <p class="pull-right">Projects completed: 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row c-notes">
       <label>Manager Note:</label>
       <input class="form-control">
    </div>        
  </div>
```

I want input takes all space after label. I know that I can use `col-**` classes but then on high resolution there will be some space between label and input, but I don't need this space.

Look at [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zokeresuri/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **CSS Flexbox**. Like:

```
.c-notes {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.c-notes label {
  flex: 0 auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.c-notes input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Have a look at the **first textfield** in the snippet below or have a look at the updated **[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kunoweweqi/1/edit?html,css,output)**.

```css
.c-notes {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.c-notes label {
  flex: 0 auto;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.c-notes input {
  flex: 1;
}
.comment {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p class="comment">My try, I just use witdh proeprty, but it also has problem with different resolution.</p>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="pull-left">Name: <strong>John Smith</strong></p>
        <p class="pull-right">Projects completed: 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row c-notes">
       <label>Manager Note:</label>
       <input class="form-control">
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <hr/>
  <p class="comment">Option 2, use col-xx class, but there is space between label and input, increae ouput window and you will see.</p>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="pull-left">Name: <strong>John Smith</strong></p>
        <p class="pull-right">Projects completed: 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-sm-2">Manager Note:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Note">
            </div>          
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just Add below css rules.

```
.c-notes {
    display: flex;
}
```

See below

```css
.c-notes{
   display: flex;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="pull-left">Name: <strong>John Smith</strong></p>
        <p class="pull-right">Projects completed: 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row c-notes">
       <label>Manager Note:</label>
       <input class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```